# Write specific bytes inside a file using lua

Tags: lua

I want to write a specific byte inside a .txt file, for example:
Text File

> Something

Code

> Som4thing

I want to do like that, but without overwriting the whole file using io.write().

I hope it was easy to understand my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to figure out what mode to open the file in. `r` won't let you write, so it's out. `a` and `a+` will only ever let you write to the end, so they're out. `w` and `w+` erase the whole file, so they're out. That leaves `r+`.

Next, you need to get to the right place in the file. The `seek` function does that. In your case, you want to go to 3 bytes past the beginning.

Finally, simply write your data and close the file.

```
local file = io.open('filename.txt', 'r+')
file:seek('set', 3)
file:write('4')
file:close()
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually didn't know you could do `f:write()`, I always did `io.input(f) io.write('4')`. And I actually appreciate that you answer pretty fast.

Comment: I just noticed, the byte I want to open will be always the letter position minus 1?

Comment: @ProgrammingIsLearning Yeah, it's zero-based, unlike pretty much everything else in Lua.